# unable to save log into windows azure table storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have used following code to save trace log into table storage.
I'm using windows azure skd version 2.2

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("START Log");
```

also added `listener` in  `web.config`

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

also added code in `webrole.cs`

```
public override bool OnStart()
        {
            StartDiagnostics();
            return base.OnStart();
        }

        private void StartDiagnostics()
        {
            DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration dmc = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
            TimeSpan tsOneMinute = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            // Transfer logs to storage every minute
            dmc.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = tsOneMinute;
            // Transfer verbose, critical, etc. logs
            dmc.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;
            // Start up the diagnostic manager with the given configuration.
            try
            {
                DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", dmc);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

            }
        }
```

> Still getting error : 500 internal server error

Comment: 500 internal error from *where*?

Comment: user context - authentication 
I check when I insert listener code in web.config then this error comes

Comment: Can you ensure that you have configured azure diagnostics correctly using instructions from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh411537.aspx).